# Cannot install wine and playonlinux due to 404 errors?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

As the title says I am a Ubuntu 12.04 user without any particular unix experience. I am a (somewhat rusty) fully qualified MSCE engineer who has made the mistake of switching to management :-).

I have just istalled ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop and it works fine.

I am now looking for ways of connecting to itunes, in order to access my account there. In other blogs and forums I read that I need to install playonlinux, which I have tried to do. However, although the internet connection is working fine for firefox, I get an error in Ubuntu Software Centre. It says `failed to download package files`. The details reveal that:

```
Failed to fetch http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/winbind_3.6.3-2ubuntu2.3_i386.deb 404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/libpam-winbind_3.6.3-2ubuntu2.3_i386.deb 404  Not Found
```

Can anyone tell me where to find these .deb files?

Comment: You want winbind_3.6.3-2ubuntu2.4_i386.deb (that one isn on the dutch server so Oli is probably correct)

Comment: iTunes doesn't work with playonlinux (wine) except for very old versions. Are you sure you want to install this?

Answer (score 3):

"Not found" errors from the official repositories are usually a sign that your local package list is out of date. If this is a very new install (as your post suggests) this is even more likely. The installer really aught to do this but there you go.

Run a `sudo apt-get update` (or use a graphical package manager to update) and you should find that those sorts of errors evaporate.

Answer (score 1):

Find PlayOnLinux via the Software Center, and then click the "Visit developers site", and then choose the Ubuntu version, and it will download the .deb files. If you download via the Software Center to start with, it will download an older version.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the following:

```
sudo aptitude update
```

then:

```
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
```

and:

```
sudo aptitude install wine1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're downloading from the nl. subdomain. Try changing download source, in System Settings, under Software Sources. To a server like UK. Then run `sudo apt-get update`.